# ERROR in src/app/services/generateReport.service.ts(2,16): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'require'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

In my app, I need to generate a report in the form of a word Document with a click of a button.
Using the "officeGen" module, I have managed to do so in a separate project.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/officegen

> generateDoc.ts

```
const officegen = require('officegen')
const fs = require('fs')

// Create an empty PowerPoint object:
let pptx = officegen('pptx')

// Officegen calling this function after finishing to generate the pptx document:
pptx.on('finalize', function(written) {
  console.log(
    'Finish to create a Microsoft PowerPoint document.'
  )
})

// Officegen calling this function to report errors:
pptx.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err)
})

// Let's add a title slide:

let slide = pptx.makeTitleSlide('Officegen', 'Example to a PowerPoint document')

// Pie chart slide example:

slide = pptx.makeNewSlide()
slide.name = 'Pie Chart slide'
slide.back = 'ffff00'
slide.addChart(
  {
    title: 'My production',
    renderType: 'pie',
    data:
    [
      {
        name: 'Oil',
        labels: ['Czech Republic', 'Ireland', 'Germany', 'Australia', 'Austria', 'UK', 'Belgium'],
        values: [301, 201, 165, 139, 128,  99, 60],
        colors: ['ff0000', '00ff00', '0000ff', 'ffff00', 'ff00ff', '00ffff', '000000']
      }
    ]
  }
)

// Let's generate the PowerPoint document into a file:

let out = fs.createWriteStream('example.pptx')

out.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err)
})

// Async call to generate the output file:
pptx.generate(out)
```

To integrate these functionalities, I created a service in my Angular project containing the previous code:

> generateReport.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
const async = require("async");
const officegen = require("officegen");

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");


@Injectable()
export class generateReport {

  constructor() {}
/**
 *
 *
  //var outDir = path.join(__dirname, '../tmp/')

  // var themeXml = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'themes/testTheme.xml'), 'utf8')
  createDoc() {
    var docx = officegen({
      type: "docx",
      orientation: "portrait",
      pageMargins: {
        top: 1000,
        left: 1000,
        bottom: 1000,
        right: 1000
      }
      // The theme support is NOT working yet...
      // themeXml: themeXml
    });

    // Remove this comment in case of debugging Officegen:
    // officegen.setVerboseMode ( true )

    docx.on("error", function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

    pObj = docx.createP({
      align: "center"
    });

    pObj.addText(" Risk Analysis Report", {
      font_face: "Arial",
      font_size: 40
    });
    //pObj.addLineBreak()
    pObj = docx.createP({
      backline: "E0E0E0"
    });

    pObj.addText("Author: Sami Habboubi", {
      bold: true
    });
    pObj = docx.createP({
      backline: "E0E0E0"
    });

    pObj.addText("Date: 11/06/2019");

    pObj = docx.createP({
      align: "center"
    });

    pObj.addText("Business Process General Information", {
      border: "dotted",
      borderSize: 12,
      borderColor: "88CCFF",
      bold: true
    });

    var table = [
      [
        {
          opts: {
            cellColWidth: 4261,
            b: true,
            sz: "10",
            shd: {
              fill: "7F7F7F",
              themeFill: "Arial",
              themeFillTint: "20"
            },
            fontFamily: "Arial"
          }
        },
        {
          opts: {
            b: true,
            align: "left",
            shd: {
              fill: "92CDDC",
              themeFill: "text1",
              themeFillTint: "80"
            },
            fontFamily: "Avenir Book"
          }
        }
      ],
      [
        "1. What are your main business objectives? ",
        "All grown-ups were once children"
      ],
      [
        "2. In which sites(Countries) your team is located?",
        "there is no harm in putting off a piece of work until another day."
      ],
      [
        "3. What are your key business processes? How are they ranked in terms of criticality?",
        "4. But when it is a matter of baobabs, that always means a catastrophe."
      ],
      [
        "5. What are your main interactions with other Business Lines?",
        "watch out for the baobabs!"
      ]
    ];

    var tableStyle = {
      tableColWidth: 4261,
      tableSize: 24,
      tableColor: "ada",
      tableAlign: "left",
      tableFontFamily: "Arial"
    };

    pObj = docx.createTable(table, tableStyle);

    docx.putPageBreak();

    var pObj = docx.createP();

    pObj.addText("Simple");
    pObj.addText(" with color", {
      color: "000088"
    });
    pObj.addText(" and back color.", {
      color: "00ffff",
      back: "000088"
    });

    pObj = docx.createP();

    pObj.addText("Since ");
    pObj.addText("officegen 0.2.12", {
      back: "00ffff",
      shdType: "pct12",
      shdColor: "ff0000"
    }); // Use pattern in the background.
    pObj.addText(" you can do ");
    pObj.addText("more cool ", {
      highlight: true
    }); // Highlight!
    pObj.addText("stuff!", {
      highlight: "darkGreen"
    }); // Different highlight color.

    pObj = docx.createP();

    pObj.addText("Even add ");
    pObj.addText("external link", {
      link: "https://github.com"
    });
    pObj.addText("!");

    pObj = docx.createP();

    pObj.addText("Bold + underline", {
      bold: true,
      underline: true
    });

    pObj = docx.createP({
      align: "center"
    });

    pObj.addText("Center this text", {
      border: "dotted",
      borderSize: 12,
      borderColor: "88CCFF"
    });

    pObj = docx.createP();
    pObj.options.align = "right";

    pObj.addText("Align this text to the right.");

    pObj = docx.createP();

    pObj.addText("Those two lines are in the same paragraph,");
    pObj.addLineBreak();
    pObj.addText("but they are separated by a line break.");

    docx.putPageBreak();

    pObj = docx.createP();

    pObj.addText("Fonts face only.", {
      font_face: "Arial"
    });
    pObj.addText(" Fonts face and size.", {
      font_face: "Arial",
      font_size: 40
    });

    docx.putPageBreak();

    pObj = docx.createP();

    //pObj.addImage(path.resolve(__dirname, 'images_for_examples/image3.png'))

    docx.putPageBreak();

    pObj = docx.createP();

    //pObj.addImage(path.resolve(__dirname, 'images_for_examples/image1.png'))

    pObj = docx.createP();

    //pObj.addImage(path.resolve(__dirname, 'images_for_examples/sword_001.png'))
    //pObj.addImage(path.resolve(__dirname, 'images_for_examples/sword_002.png'))
    //pObj.addImage(path.resolve(__dirname, 'images_for_examples/sword_003.png'))
    //pObj.addText('... some text here ...', { font_face: 'Arial' })
    //pObj.addImage(path.resolve(__dirname, 'images_for_examples/sword_004.png'))

    pObj = docx.createP();

    //pObj.addImage(path.resolve(__dirname, 'images_for_examples/image1.png'))

    docx.putPageBreak();

    pObj = docx.createListOfNumbers();

    pObj.addText("Option 1");

    pObj = docx.createListOfNumbers();

    pObj.addText("Option 2");

    pObj.addHorizontalLine();

    pObj = docx.createP({
      backline: "E0E0E0"
    });

    pObj.addText("Backline text1");

    pObj.addText(" text2");

    pObj = docx.createP();

    pObj.addText("Strikethrough text", {
      strikethrough: true
    });

    pObj.addText("superscript", {
      superscript: true
    });
    pObj.addText("subscript", {
      subscript: true
    });

    var out = fs.createWriteStream(path.join("Risk Analysis Report.docx"));

    out.on("error", function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

    async.parallel(
      [
        function(done) {
          out.on("close", function() {
            console.log("Finish to create a DOCX file.");
            done(null);
          });
          docx.generate(out);
        }
      ],
      function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error: " + err);
        } // Endif.
      }
    );
  }
 */
}
```

And I intended to call that service in app.Componenet.ts and run it in the method that would be binded with the button.
However, the first four "require" lines cause these errors in the Angular project (The code works perfectly when it is run in a separate project):
[image]

> ERROR in src/app/services/generateReport.service.ts(2,15): error
>   TS2580: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type
>   definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to
>   the types field in your tsconfig.
>   src/app/services/generateReport.service.ts(3,19): error TS2580: Cannot
>   find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node?
>   Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your
>   tsconfig. src/app/services/generateReport.service.ts(5,12): error
>   TS2580: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type
>   definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to
>   the types field in your tsconfig.
>   src/app/services/generateReport.service.ts(6,14): error TS2580: Cannot
>   find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node?
>   Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your
>   tsconfig.

I have tried:

> npm install --save @types/node

But, it didn't solve the issue.
So here are my questions:
1/ Why do I only receive those errors in the Angular project and not in the separate project?
2/ Is there a way to solve this?
3/ Is my way of implementing a service and calling its methods in the main component is the right way to go about solving this generating report task?
Thank you, all!

Comment: There's a difference between node development and browser development (Angular). You don't use `require` in the browser unless you're using a library which allows it (e.g., [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/)). If you do a search for "Cannot find name 'require'" you'll find plenty of questions about it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for the info :) ... But I don't see an alternative for using require

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved this problem this way:

```
import * as async from "async";
import * as officegen from "officegen";
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as path from "path";
```